# CSS set two elements same height and 100% width

Tags: css, flexbox

This might have been asked already, in which case I apologize. I'm trying to put a video next to an image. The video has fixed dimensions but the image can be any ratio. I know that to make the elements same height, I'd use a flexbox. But to make them 100% width of the page, I don't know what to do. Is this more of a math problem than a CSS problem (trying to figure out the dimensions of the image)?

Comment: fixed dimensions or fixed ratio?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using a grid. Here's a basic example:

```css
.grid-container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "grid-left grid-right";
}

.grid-left { grid-area: grid-left; }

.grid-right { grid-area: grid-right; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-left"></div>
  <div class="grid-right"></div>
</div>
```